# Combo Box and Drop Down not showing correct options

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, power-platform

In my Power App, I am using a Combo Box to allow users to select an option from a choice column in the connected SharePoint list.

Instead of the Combo box showing the different options that it should, it shows a large blank list with several hundred values. The same thing happens when I try to use a regular Drop Down.

I have tried deleting the Combo box, and the SharePoint column, and starting again but neither solved my issue.

The SharePoint column in a regular Choice column with two values, and the formula inside the combo box is  'Name of List"."Name of Column"

Here is what the Drop Down looks like currently, like I said above it should only have 2 values, but instead is showing hundreds of blank values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding going on here.

What you are trying to achieve is getting the the options the users are allowed to choose from in this field (e.g. the options set when you created the column).

By referencing the choice column of the SharePoint list like you did 'Name of list'.'Name of Column', you are telling PowerApps to fetch all rows from the SP list and show the actual values form your choice field. They're probably empty because the rows preexisted before you added the choice column.

My suggestions

1. Solution A

- Define the options to choose from explicitly in the Items property of the element in PowerApps
- Set the field in your original SP list to be single line of text to accept the form submissions

2. Solution B

- Create a new SP list with a single line of text field
- Add the options to choose from as rows to this new list
- Set the field in your original SP list to be single line of text to accept the form submissions (you can also try setting the column to be of type Lookup)
- Reference this list in the Items property of the PowerApps control.

Answer (score 0):

When we add 'Name of List'.'Name of Column'  formula to ComboBox's Item property (`**Ex: 'CM_Account Master'.'Account Name'**`),
We have to set 4 more properties also,

1. Display Fields: ["AccountName"]
2. Search Field: ["AccountName"]
   Refer [ComboBox properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP864.png)
3. Allow Searching: true
4. Allow Multi Selection: true/false
   Refer [ComboBox Allow Multi Select/Allow Searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1yWi.png)

After setting "***DisplayFields***" you can able to view results instead of a blank dropdown list.